# Quelle traduction pour "a cautionary tale" ?

Tags: traduction

Je cherche une traduction adéquate pour l'expression "a cautionary tale". Les traducteurs en ligne proposent "une histoire édifiante", mais ce n'est pas ce que cela signifie.

Un "cautionary tale" est une histoire, qui peut-être fictive, ou bien passée, porteuse d'enseignements, pour éviter à l'avenir de se retrouver à nouveau dans une situation similaire et peu souhaitable. La fable de [L'enfant qui criait au loup](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Enfant_qui_criait_au_loup) est par exemple un "cautionary tale".

Un traduction littérale serait "un conte qui apprend à faire attention", ou "un conte qui prévient de dangers", mais existe-t-il une formule équivalente et plus littéraire en français ?

Comment: "Cautionary tale" est un idiome dans lequel "tale" est souvent utilisé dans un sens métaphorique. L'expression pourrait alors se traduire par **leçon de prudence**.

Comment: En cherchant dans DeepL.com : Un récit qui met en garde, qui incite à la prudence, en forme d'avertissement, alarmant (ou inquiétant).

Comment: "l'appelle à la prudence"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Cautionary tale" est une expression dans laquelle "tale" est souvent utilisé
> dans un sens métaphorique. L'expression pourrait alors se traduire par
> **leçon de prudence**. ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53572/quelle-traduction-pour-a-cautionary-tale#comment113982_53572), en commentaire sous licence [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing))

Answer (score 4):

Je trouve qu'"édifiant" convient assez bien ici. On "édifie" le lecteur pour qu'il soit renseigné, et évite le problème plus tard, ce qui paraît être un sens reconnu pour *édification* par le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?27;s=2556931410;r=2;nat=;sol=1;) (sens B), par exemple.

Sinon, on peut se rabattre sur *histoire/conte/fable avec une morale*, dont le plus bel exemple est bien sûr les célèbres Fables de La Fontaine. Ou bien même une périphrase complète: *histoire qui sert d'avertissement*.

Mais je suis d'accord que *morale* et *édification* ne correspondent peut-être pas tout à fait à *caution* en Anglais. *Histoire qui sert d'avertissement* est peut-être l'approximation la plus proche, puisque *caution* peut se traduire par *avertissement*.

Comment: C'est vrai qu'étymologiquement, "édifiant" n'est en fait pas si mauvais. Mais j'ai le sentiment que dans le langage commun, "édifiant" est plus entendu comme "stupéfiant, surprenant" que comme "porteur d'enseignements".

Comment: @FrançoisM. Pour moi, j'ai toujours associé _édification_ à _éducation_ aussi en large. Je ne l'ai jamais compris ou associé avec _surprise_, et les dictionnaires ne semblent pas aller dans ce sens. Je rapprocherais plutôt _édification_ du mot _Bildung_ en Allemand, et on ne peut ignorer aussi le sens _construire_ du mot _édifier_, à mon avis. Je pense qu'on est bel et bien dans le registre de la _construction du caractère_.

Comment: @FrançoisM. Bizarre. Je me demande d'où le sens de "étonnant" pour "édifiant" peut venir, ou si vous avez des exemples. Les dictionnaires ne semblent pas évoquer ce sens, et "édifier" étant un synonyme de "construire", je ne vois pas comment passer à "étonnant".

Comment: "Histoire édifiante" est effectivement assez exacte au niveau du sens mais assez différent dans l'usage comparé à *cautionary tale*, car rarement utilisée de nos jours et réservé au contexte des contes et fables. Dans un contexte journalistique, on voit le plus souvent : servir de leçon, d'avertissement, mise en garde, d'exemple (à ne pas suivre).

Answer (score 1):

> En cherchant dans DeepL.com : Un récit qui met en garde, qui incite à
> la prudence, en forme d'avertissement, alarmant (ou inquiétant).
> ([Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53572/quelle-traduction-pour-a-cautionary-tale#comment113992_53572), en commentaire sous licence [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing))

Answer (score 0):

Ce sont les [fables](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable), de la tradition orale, point final. Soit Ésope, soit La Fontaine, ce genre de conte de fée, une  morale : ces allégories, ce sont des fables.  En effet  ça fait partie de poser le cadre et élever les enfants.

> Une fable est un court récit en vers ou en prose qui vise à donner de
> façon plaisante une leçon de vie. Elle se caractérise souvent par un
> récit fictif de composition naïve et allégorique mettant en scène des
> animaux qui parlent, des êtres humains ou d’autres entités à l'aspect
> animal, mais personnifiés[1](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable). Une morale est exprimée à la fin ou au
> début de la fable. Celle-ci est parfois implicite, le lecteur devant
> la dégager lui-même.

Answer (score 0):

Bien souvent, la bonne traduction sera une reformulation et pas une traduction direct de cette expression.

Voilà quelques exemples tirés du [Cambridge Dictionnary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cautionary-tale):

> His career is recalled today as a cautionary tale of economic mismanagement.

> Sa carrière sert de leçon en matière de mauvais management économique.

> "Frankenstein" is a cautionary tale about the dangers of science.

> *Frankenstein* nous met en garde contre les dangers de la science.

> As a cautionary tale, the novel is a success.

> Le roman joue bien son rôle de mise en garde.

En termes de définitions, une "fable" est très proche d'un "cautionary tale", mais les connotations sont très différentes, au point que c'est quasiment toujours une erreur de traduire l'un par l'autre. En effet, qualifier quelque chose de "fable" c'est avant-tout insister sur son aspect fictif (et donc fantaisiste et pas vraiment à prendre au sérieux), là où le "cautionary tale" est en principe à prendre au sérieux.